# How to extract specific ids

Tags: excel

There is probably an easy way to do this. Just cant figure it out.

I have a huge dataset with multiple id:s that can have different code (column 2). How do I go about to extract by specific code "x" in this case and also extract all the ids that contains even one x. See image

[image]

Comment: How do you want to 'Extract'? One way would be to hit 'Sort and filter' on the Home tab, then in the dropdown of the column you want, use 'text filters' > 'Contains' > x

Comment: Just a suggestion y don't you use filter

Comment: Your result also showing `y`?

Comment: Clarification: I have a dataset with patient IDs in column A; a unique patient can have multiple diagnosis-codes. I want to extract all patients according to diagnosis X and at the same time include all IDs for that patient even if that patient also have another diagnosis Y or Z,D,etc... I want to exclude all other patients that do not contain diagnosis X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it seems you are trying to filter IDs excluding code `c`. If I am correct then use below formula to `E2` cell. If my assumption if wrong then please explain how your output is coming.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW($A$1))/($B$2:$B$12<>"c"),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]

> Edit after clarification: Only for `Office365` excel.

So, if you have `Office365` excel then use below formula as per screenshot

```
E2=FILTER(A2:A12,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A12,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A12,B2:B12="x")),0)))
F2=FILTER(B2:B12,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A12,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A12,B2:B12="x")),0)))
```

> If you do not have `Office365` then you need to use combinations of few formulas by array entry which will slow your excel performance. Here is array formulas.

```
E2=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW($A$1))/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$12,IF($B$2:$B$12="x",$A$2:$A$12,""),0))),ROW(1:1))),"")
F2=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$12)-ROW($A$1))/(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$12,IF($B$2:$B$12="x",$A$2:$A$12,""),0))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: This was a simplification, I have more variables in column B: x,c,z,d,g, etc...see my clarification above.

Comment: No issue with big dataset just expand range to formula like `A1:B20000`.

Comment: But there is a problem because I want to include all IDs with X and whatever other diagnosis there can be for that same patient, which can also include e.g. c

Comment: Understood your issue. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Harun24HR, the formula worked. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Ilja Welcome! If you found the answer useful then please mark it as accepted. Tick mark it.